# How to check if a given Markov chain is positive recurrent.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm trying to solve a problem which is related to my research, and I have to check whether this infinite-state Markov chain is positive recurrent or not.

Suppose the Markov chain I have has state 0, state 1, ... state n, ... At any given state i, the expected next state is less than i. I know this fact:

E[ S_{i+1} | S_{i} ] - S_{i} < 0.

So, I think this somehow will give me a way to prove that the Markov chain will end up being around state 0, state 1, ... state m, where m is a small value. But, I can't find any method of doing it.

Can anybody have any idea as to how to prove that the Markov chain is positive recurrent?

Thanks.

Comment: How can it be that "At any given state i, the expected next state is less than i"? If you are at state 0, expected next state is greater or equal to zero. So, inequality can not be strict.

Comment: Is it a continuous time Markov chain?

Comment: Artem: You are right. I wasnt clear about that. Unless the current state is 0, the expected next state is lower than the current state.

Comment: Ritz: It is not. It is discrete.

Comment: The condition that $E(S_{i+1}\mid S_i=n)\lt0$ for every $n\ne0$ is not sufficient to guarantee positive recurrence. Counterexamples are discrete Bessel processes of suitable indexes.

Comment: Did: Thanks for your comment. Then, is there any way to verify if the Markov chain at hand is positive recurrent?


The Markov chain that I'm considering satisfies the following:


$\sum_{i=0}^{\inf}\pi_i = 1$,

$(1-p)^2 \pi_n = -(1-p)^2 \pi_{n-1} - (2p(1-p) + (1-p)^2) \pi_{n-2} + p^2 \pi_{n-3}$, $n \geq 3$.

p is between 0 and 1.

Comment: This is somehow too detailed, so if you can give any general advice, I'd really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: See your other post, which has serious problems of its own. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did Thanks. I've been new to this forum, so I have misbehaved. Thanks for letting me know. I will be better than this!

Comment: No problem. $ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition that $E(S_{i+1}\mid S_i=n)\lt0$ for every $n\ne0$ is not sufficient to guarantee positive recurrence. Counterexamples are discrete Bessel processes of suitable indexes.

Comment: Thanks. So the fine line between positive-recurrence and null-recurrence is hard to find out by intuition...